# Kentico staging sync

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I'm trying to sync page changes from my local environment to the UAT environment using the Staging module in Kentico. I've set up the source and destination servers but when I try to sync a specific page it throws the following error.

> No Route Value Found No DynamicRouting assembly tag was found for the
> class CMS.Root, could not route page

am I missing anything here? We are using Kentico 12 MVC

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible you are using DynamicRouting: https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/DynamicRouting ? Maybe it is interfering somehow with the staging requests?

Comment: @jurajo Yes, I’m using dynamic routing but why and how does it affect staging?

Comment: It is a 3rd party code - so I am unable to tell how it is interfering. Just guessing based on the error - "DynamicRouting assembly" - this is not a default Kentico thing. I would try removing the module to see if it helps. If yes. submit an issue to the author of the DynamicRouting module on Github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the URL of the destination server. You may have provided URL of your UAT MVC application, however it should be the URL of your UAT CMS Admin site.

Answer (score 0):

I think though Dmitry is correct, I think your staging module is pointing to the wrong environment.

If it is pointing to the admin, you may have the mvc only module installed on the admin, but I don't think it would even compile at that point.